# UrlEncoding - which encoding should I use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

Using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and passing via the URL the receiving page sees the variables as:

> brand new -> brand+new
>   Airconaire+Ltd -> Airconaire+Ltd

Can you see how the first and the second **both** have a + in them where they didn't at the start?  I'm assuming this is something to do with the encoding (specifically RFC3986 or RFC2396) but how do I solve this?

I think ideally the spaces should be converted to %20 but is this the best way forward?

Comment: If you're saying that UrlPathEncode() is not working for you, can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` rather than URLEncode.

Comment: Thanks - but what is the reason why UrlPathEncode works over UrlEncode?

Comment: UrlPathEncode uses a platform agnostic encoding method whereas UrlEncode uses a Microsoft approach (I believe).

Comment: So I should go through my app replacing every instance of UrlEncode to UrlPathEncode?

Comment: If you want consistent results regardless of browser/OS from the clients accessing it then Yes.

Comment: Thanks - so why on earth is this a problem in the first place?  Everyone wants consistent results on the web, yet the going advice is use UrlEncode

Comment: The UrlEncode documentation on MSDN does actually state that you should use UrlPathEncode for consistent cross-platform operation. I suspect UrlEncode is a legacy name that was carried forward as MS moved to a more open approach to their tools.

Comment: UrlPathEncode does the same thing - just tried it.  If I try to encode a + it gets ignored

Comment: What do you want to happen to the +?

Comment: UrlPathEncode should encode a space to %20:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx

Comment: @m.edmonson: The URI encoding specification states that the query section of the URI can consist of pchar / "/" / "?", pchar is defined as unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@", the relevant element here is sub-delims which are "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "=". In this for the unquoted slash means or. As you can see the "+" is perfectly valid so wouldn't be unnecessarily percent encoded. You can check out the entire spec here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 1):

The UrlEncode() method can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values. If characters such as blanks and punctuation are passed in an HTTP stream, they might be misinterpreted at the receiving end. URL encoding converts characters that are not allowed in a URL into character-entity equivalents; URL decoding reverses the encoding. For example, when the characters < and > are embedded in a block of text to be transmitted in a URL, they are encoded as %3c and %3e.

You can encode a URL using with the UrlEncode() method or the UrlPathEncode() method. However, the methods return different results. The UrlEncode() method converts each space character to a plus character (+). The UrlPathEncode() method converts each space character into the string "%20", which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use the UrlPathEncode() method when you encode the path portion of a URL in order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which platform or browser performs the decoding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx